# After migration product page & category page giving 404 error page

Tags: magento-1.7, migration, 404-page, magento2-migration-tool

I have migrate in magento 1.7.0.2 to Magento 2.0.4.

All things are working fine except product page & category page giving 404 error.

Is there any idea to resolve it ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you run indexing?

Comment: yes I have rei-ndex and flush cache both

Comment: Have you idea how magneto 2 url_rewrite works ? because if i have truncate  url_rewrite table its working fine but url structure changed.